# Bootstrap multiple Angular2 Apps on the same page

Tags: javascript, angular

After searching the whole internet for a practical solution, I'll try here:

I'm new to Angular2 although I have a few years of experience with react and vue. Currently I'm working on a pretty big project where the content is based in components composed in the java backend and downloaded as static markup to the client. Every now and then, we need to include some Angular4 tools in those pages. Those tools are completely unrelated to each other but have to coexist with each other and the static markup surrounding them.

The code for all tools comes bundled in the same single javascript file and Angular will decide which tool to render depending on which parameters are present in the page. This works already when there is only one app to mount in the page but fails for all apps except the first one when there are many.

Any help more than appreciated!

Following are excerpts of the code:

**Main.ts**

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if ( environment.production ) {
  enableProdMode();
}

const roots = document.getElementsByTagName('db-app');

for (var index = 0; index < roots.length; index++) {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule( AppModule );
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoreModule } from './core/core.module';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';

import { ExpertSearchModule } from './expertSearch/expertSearch.module';
import { InstalmentCalculatorModule } from './instalmentCalculator/instalmentCalculator.module';

/**
 * The App Module, this should be empty by definition :)
 */
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule,
    ExpertSearchModule,
    InstalmentCalculatorModule,
  ],
})

export class AppModule {
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'db-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})

export class AppComponent {
  // from AEM
  public src: any;
  public compName: string;
  /**
   * This is the entry point for all data coming from AEM
   */
  constructor(private _elementRef : ElementRef) {
    const src = _elementRef.nativeElement;
    const srcId = src.getAttribute('data-comp-id');

    this.src = window[srcId],
    this.compName = src.getAttribute('data-comp-name');
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<db-expert-search *ngIf="compName == 'expertSearch'" [data]="src"></db-expert-search>
<db-instalment-calculator *ngIf="compName == 'instalmentCalculator'" [data]="src"></db-instalment-calculator>
```

**host page html**

```
<script>
  var instalmentCalculator_parsys_nginstalmentcalculat = {
    // configuration options...
  };
</script>
<db-app 
  data-comp-name="instalmentCalculator" 
  data-comp-id="instalmentCalculator_parsys_nginstalmentcalculat">
  Loading...
</db-app>

<script>
  var expertSearch_parsys_ngexpertsearch = {
    // configuration options...
  };
</script>

<db-app 
  data-comp-name="expertSearch" 
  data-comp-id="expertSearch_parsys_ngexpertsearch">
  Loading...
</db-app>
```

Comment: Quite complex case you have there..

I think a more correct approach will be not trying to reuse your db-app component twice, but import two (or more) modules with their components and lazy load these modules into your app.

You want to show one or more tools at the same time or show just one depending on certain data (url, parameters..) ?